# Can postgresql-9.6:i386 be installed on amd64 Debian(9) build?

Tags: debian, postgresql, 32bit

So I am currently running a Debian 9 64-bit LINUX build (for some background).

I have installed unixODBC (compiled as 32 bit) and `odbc-postgresql:i386`, now the final piece should be to install the actual `postgresql-9.6 rdms`.

I am attempting to accomplish this via a simple tried and true call to apt-get...

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.6:i386
```

Unfortunately I get some unmet dependencies as shown below...

```
root@linux2:/home/jeremyn/unixODBC-2.3.0# sudo apt-get install postgresql- 
9.6:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 postgresql-9.6:i386 : Depends: locales:i386 but it is not installable
                       Depends: libsystemd0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                       Recommends: postgresql-contrib-9.6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                       Recommends: sysstat:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Normally this would be a minor issue and I would simply install the necessary dependencies, but the issues seem to cascade from here...

```
Package locales:i386 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libc-l10n

E: Package 'locales:i386' has no installation candidate
```

I have also tried installing the `libc-l10n`, but again it only leads to further problems. Has anyone encountered this issue and found a way to install postgresql-9.6:i386 on a Debian 9 build?

Comment: Why do you need the 32bit version of postgres?

Comment: Well I'm not exactly sure I NEED it per say. For some additional background I'm migrating a large solution from windows to linux. I had accomplished this but was running in to a very very strange data issue. Upon looking further in to it I noticed that we were compiling the solution on windows as 32-bit so for continuity I wanted to attempt to get all 32-bit libraries and pgsql rdbms to see if that might remedy the issue. This could be totally wrong, but I thought it a valid attempt though its taken more effort than originally thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I very much doubt that installing the 32-bit version of the PostgreSQL *server* will make any difference. In any case, thanks to various issues involving the `locales` package (see [this bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=669188) for details), you won’t be able to install `postgresql-9.6:i386` on an `amd64` system; there is no workaround short of rebuilding the package yourself without the `locales` dependency.

To sum up, install `postgresql-9.6` instead, or try again on a 32-bit installation of Debian.